# Flutter Audio with Circle Progress

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I need to create a screen that plays back mp4 audio files, with play, pause, stop controls and shows progress via a circle progress indictor. Does anyone know if a package exists for this, or combination of packages?
So what I am trying to create would be similar to the following:

[image]

Comment: with those 3 dots inside? i dont think anyone already made this - you need to do it by yourself using a `CustomPainter`

Comment: No I don't need three dots, just the circle showing the progress of the audio file thats being played.

Comment: so it is [CircularProgressIndicator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CircularProgressIndicator-class.html) in `Determinate` mode, isnt it?

Comment: I don't think so, there is no property to increase the size of the progress indicator. It should be quite big filling the width of the screen. Though yes if there was a way to influence the size then this could work in determinate mode as you say

Comment: goto the link i posted and on the right side of `CircularProgressIndicator class` label there is a small blue "document" icon - clik on it and find `_CircularProgressIndicatorPainter`

Comment: @pskink Many thanks. Please add this as an answer, I will mark it done and up vote you.

Comment: feel free to make a self answer ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a clone of the Circular Progress Indicator using the documentation described by pskink in the comments [enter link description here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/0b8abb4724/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/progress_indicator.dart#L411) . Many thanks and gratitude to him for helping with this.